VS Code Local commits showing even after deleting them

the upper 2 commits are the problem
i tried doing what was answered on this similar question
i tried using chatGPT and doing commands like
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/main

and
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now

but nothing works
is there and actual solution or do i have to reclone the repo?

You mean to place local main on top of origin/main? The hard reset should work.... You were probably standing on a different place from local main. Try a checkout before running the hard reset

Ok I got some help and the problem was that i was trying to delete the commits when i was detached. I used the Checkout(Detached) button on the right click menu of the commit. after i moved to the branch properly i did
git reset --hard back to the settings button commit, pushed and then it was fixed

In SO etiquette, this is not the way to proceed. If "the help" was the comment I provided there, you should acknowledge, then ask me to write an answer. Not a big deal in this case, it's ok, but so that you are aware.

@eftshift0 I disagree. I don't see a problem with this. you can still write your own answer post if you think you can write a better one.
